# Mongoose and aggregate $out

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose in my nodejs project.

How can I transfer all documents from collection A to collection B in mongoose? Collection A does not have a model defined in mongoose, collection B does have a model defined in mongoose. I tried the following, but nothing gets copied:

```
await mongoose.connection.db
    .collection("collectionA")
    .aggregate([{ $out: "collectionB" }]);
```

I try to replicate the following query in mongosh:

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([{ $out: "collectionB" }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not running command on the server. Add .toArray() at the end:

```
await mongoose.connection.db
    .collection("collectionA")
    .aggregate([{ $out: "collectionB" }])
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Is this an update or a solution? If it is an update, [edit] your question instead of posting as answer.